# Add and merge rows based on column data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table with headings similar to the following:

```
| Year | Location | Rand | Rand | Type | Count |
```

Currently I am applying this SQL to filter it out:

```
SELECT *
FROM BOOK1
WHERE TYPE = 'Type' 
  AND Location = 'CountryA' OR Type = 'Type' 
  AND Location = 'CountryB'
ORDER BY Location ASC, YEAR ASC;
```

Which returns something like:

| Year | Location | Rand | Rand | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | CountryA | N/a | N/a | Type | 1202 |
| 2001 | CountryA | N/a | N/a | Type | 2034 |
| 2001 | CountryA | N/a | N/a | Type | 1284 |
| 2002 | CountryA | N/a | N/a | Type | 1202 |
| 2003 | CountryA | N/a | N/a | Type | 2344 |
| 2001 | CountryB | N/a | N/a | Type | 5930 |
| 2002 | CountryB | N/a | N/a | Type | 1202 |
| 2003 | CountryB | N/a | N/a | Type | 2344 |

This works well enough but unfortunately there are multiple records for the same year as seen above. I want to combine these rows so that the Year, Location and Count remain the same, The other data does not matter. Here is an example of what I want from the table above:

| Year | Location | Rand | Rand | Type | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | CountryA | N/a | N/a | Type | 1202+2034+1284 |
| 2002 | CountryA | N/a | N/a | Type | 1202 |
| 2003 | CountryA | N/a | N/a | Type | 2344 |
| 2001 | CountryB | N/a | N/a | Type | 5930 |
| 2002 | CountryB | N/a | N/a | Type | 1202 |
| 2003 | CountryB | N/a | N/a | Type | 2344 |

I have attempted to solve this using `COALESCE()` but I either cannot wrap my head around it or it is not suited for this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You want `GROUP BY` + `SUM` - group by all the columns that are the same, and sum the count.

Comment: You have a column called `Rand` twice?

Comment: I imagine you need brackets around your location clause, else you won't get back what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY` clause.

Note: Ideally avoid the use of reserved words like `YEAR`, `COUNT` or `TYPE` as column names.

```
SELECT [Year], Location, [Type], SUM(Count) [Count]
FROM BOOK1 
WHERE [Type] = 'Type' AND (Location = 'CountryA' OR Location = 'CountryB') 
GROUP BY [Year], Location, [Type]
ORDER BY Location ASC, [Year] ASC;
```

Comment: You can't just randomly mix up the column names - your answer needs to match the question.